# Model has not been found Exception while adding WFFM form in Content Editor

Tags: wffm, content-editor

I'm trying to insert a WFFM form via content editor (Presentation > Insert Form) in a page. Instead of showing the list of placeholders, it shows the page. When I add via experience editor it is fine. Using sc8.0 u5

[image]

**UPDATE:**
I see this error.

```
> 8512 20:07:08 ERROR Model has not been found Exception:
> System.ArgumentNullException Message: Value cannot be null. Parameter
> name: type Source: Sitecore.Kernel    at
> Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.ArgumentNotNull(Object argument, String
> argumentName)    at
> Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.SectionModel.GetFieldModel(String
> typestring, Item item)    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.SectionModel.Initialize(IEnumerable`1
> fields)    at
> Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.FormModel.<Initialize>b__0(Item x)    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()    at
> System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()    at
> System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)   
> at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)    at
> Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Models.FormModel.Initialize()    at
> Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.ModelFactory.GetModel(Item formItem)
```

Comment: I've seen this behavior in the past with malformed configs or with pipeline processors that are firing incorrectly. I would suggest methodically removing custom config changes until you narrow down the issue.

Comment: @jrap You mean any specific config attributes or the whole lot. Is that the only way to troubleshoot. Sounds complicated. I have updated an error log. Could you please check and see if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: I would start with pipeline modifications. You should be able to safely revert all pipelines back to defaults and still have content editor load properly. Once you determine the change that matters it's just a matter of not running it when Sitecore.Context.Site == "shell".

Comment: @jrap I have removed all the patch configs we have. It's still the same.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error. It may be worth reinstalling wffm and choosing Merge > Merge on conflicts. I would also open fiddler to see what is being requested that is causing a redirect to the front end of the site.